# error apache cordova on visual studio 2015 Android target empty

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, visual-studio-2015

Error here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDmX9.png

Hello everyone,
I updated the Android SDK and suddenly , visual studio 2015, I'm not starting more debugging on device .
Until yesterday she was .

Does anyone have any ideas? I searched and found several soluzoni but seem not to go.

Answer (score 0):

**solution**
find ***edit enviroment variables for your account*** in windows and edit PATH element with this string:

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Work for me